# How do I log into Call of Duty Live as a guest?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops, xbox-network

A few weeks ago it worked but lately whenever I try to log into live with a guest, it tells me that it can't connect to the internet, but I can log into live just on my own or with a friend using their own log in.

How do I log into Call of Duty live as a guest?

Comment: I thought you had to be (or with) a XBox live gold member to play on/with a guest. I could be wrong, but normally you can't use a lot of Xbox live services unless you are a gold member. Guests usually take the other Xbox live user's name (for example, john, and john(1)).  Edit: throwing this as my answer.

Comment: Does the data you get in a guest account save? Like call of duty etc

Answer (score 4):

I thought you had to be (or with) a XBox live gold member to play on/with a guest. I could be wrong, but normally you can't use a lot of Xbox live services unless you are a gold member. Guests usually take the other Xbox live user's name (for example, john, and john(1)).

Answer (score 0):

What version of Call of Duty are you playing? Some have bugs that have still not been fixed. I ran into this problem once while playing Black Ops and all I had to do was sign my guest in before I started the game :-). It may not be as easy for you but it's worth a shot.